# jQuery 1.11.1 appendChild error IE8 (Unexpected call to method or property access)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

SOLVED: I was appending to SECTION tag, whereas IE8 doesn't support this tag, parsing it as text/non-closed html tag, infamous cause to halt append! so I added a condition that creates HTML5 elements for IE versions below 9, as portrayed here and the problem went away, it actually fixed a bunch of other bugs as well! http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/

Sorry everyone. :(

Testing a new website I built on IE8, using jQuery v1.x (1.11.1). Using HTML5, code is validated.

I have this snippet inside a success function of an ajax function:

```
$('.product_details_contact_form_wrapper').detach().appendTo('#primary');
```

For some reason, under Chrome and Firefox it's all dandy, IE11 as well. Problem occurs when I set IE11 to emulate IE8. Then, I get a script pause and IE is complaining over appendChild in the jquery library code:

IE11(8) Inspector directs to `b.appendChild(a)`, marked with yellow and:

> "Unexpected call to method or property access." marked with red, beneath it.

[image]

Comment: jquery `append` is JS native => `innerHTML+=`

Comment: I see, but how does it help to me to solve this bug? thanks

Comment: I think the suggestion is that from Avril is that you could switch to innerHTML if you needed to.

Comment: Please consider creating a fiddle on jsfiddle.net or a similar side (or a stack snippet inside your answer) that illustrates this issue - there is a lot of code involved we can't see.

Comment: Internet explorer 8 does this whenever it encounters invalid markup in the added tags. IE11 as well as other browsers on the other hand attempt to correct the HTML. You're getting this error because you have invalid HTML. Try `alert`ing or `console.log`ing  `'<div class="product_display" style="width:' + (product_w*2) + 'px; height:' + (product_h*2-nav_h) + 'px; margin-top:' + nav_h + 'px;">' + data + '</div>';` and let us know what HTML you get.

Comment: Does the element that you're trying to append to exist?

Comment: Yes it does exist. I'll put the appended code inside the console log.

Comment: Check your `product_w`, `product_h` and `nav_h` - the result of calculations for width and height should not be negative!

Comment: I put my appended code to the validator, set the same doctype and it's returning errors that I shouldn't use a 'value' attribute on li tags nested in a ul. I should use OL instead. I'm guessing that's the culprit so I'll replace the UL with OL and let you know.

Comment: OK, I corrected all html errors and still receive this error in IE8.

Comment: please add the photograph about the error

Comment: Your code has divs, but now you're talking about lists....    what are we actually working with here?

Comment: Yep, the data appended with the appended div contains more html. So I had UL in there and the UL had LI tags with value attributes. Apparently it is wrong to use a value attribute on LI tags nested in a UL, you need to use OL. So I figured it might be what's halting IE8, but I fixed that, verified that I fixed it and it's still popping with the exact same error.

Avril, I added a snapshot.

Comment: Apparently the problem wasn't the appended div. It was an appendTo that I used before appending that div. I edited my question with the correct snippet causing the issue. Sorry everyone.

Comment: Please show us the actual HTML that you are trying to append.

Comment: Okay, after significant research, I think I found out the issue. So, the thing that causes this issue, is an element I'm trying to append from the original window to a new window. I set that element to detach and append to a newly created div element and apparently IE doesn't like to append original elements. As per here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8010

Comment: Please remove the "answer" from your question and post it as an answer.

Comment: Please post your answer as the answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the time it took me to update this question. Ok, so the ultimate solution to this problem was adding html5shiv to my project. That's it. Ignore my previous comments.